# How do I prevent checked menu items in a NavigationView from appearing with bold text?

Tags: material-components-android, navigationview, android-navigationview

As of version `1.8.0-alpha03` of the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) library, checked menu items in a [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView) are rendered with bold text. I have created [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-material-experiments/tree/main/app1) minimal application to demonstrate the change in behaviour.

Is there any way that I can instruct the [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView) to not render checked menu items with bold text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as of version `1.11.0-alpha01` of the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) library, there's a `itemTextAppearanceActiveBoldEnabled` property on the [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView) class which you can set to `false` to prevent it from rendering checked menu items with bold text.

I have created a minimal application [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-material-experiments/blob/main/app2) which demonstrates this new property.